# Open new window without blank URL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using following ajax function and need open new window after executing ajax function in given URL. New window redirected to the correct URL but shows URL as a blank. And it blocks browser as a popup. I want to open given link in new tab by showing correct URL and without blocking as a popup. I go through some relevant questions but not solved my question. Here is my ajax my ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
type: "post",
url:'http://example.com/xxx/iosapi/index/index',
data: {
    preview_image: image1,
    print_image: image2,
    product_id: productID,
    firstname: '<?php echo $customer->getFirstname(); ?>',
    lastname: '<?php echo $customer->getLastname(); ?>',
    cusemail: '<?php echo $customer->getEmail(); ?>',
    password: '<?php echo $customer->getPasswordHash(); ?>',
    qty: '1'
}
})

.done(function(data){
    hideLoader();
    url = 'https://examples.com/xxx/checkout/cart/';
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    with(win.document)
    {
    open();
    write(data);
    close();
    }
}
```

Comment: "without blocking as a popup." you cant tell the browser(or user) what to do. opening new windows\tabs is almost always a bad idea, which is why we all block that

Comment: [Do not use `with` as it may have compatibility issues and never recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). Besides, `window.open` works well and opens the url in new tab by default, you do not have to mention `_blank` with it. Try that. For more info [visit here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: @nogad The cart page need to open in new tab because some data in previous page should be kept as it is. So is there any method to do that?

Comment: that makes no sense

Comment: @Rohit416 Is there any substitute for `with`

Answer (score 0):

Try with Jquery post method

```
$.post(url, function (data) {
    var win=window.open('about:blank');
    with(win.document)
    {
      open();
      write(data);
      close();
    }
});
```

Comment: same problem occurs.

Comment: What kind of problem

Comment: New window redirected to the correct URL but shows URL as a blank. And it blocks browser as a popup.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on the browsers implementation.
There is nothing you can do to force it open in new window or tab without the permission of browser.
But you can handle this using below script.

```
var popUrl = window.open('urlgoes here', '_blank');
if (popUrl) { //Browser has allowed it to be opened
    win.focus();
} else { //Browser has blocked it
    alert('Please allow popups for this website');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ajax code success callback,

$.ajax({
        url : 'example.com',
        type: 'GET',
        success : handleData
    })

Or ajax form submit,

$("#theForm").ajaxForm({url: 'server.php', type: 'post'})